# How to write sparse Global Secondary Index rows in AWS CDK 2.0?

Tags: python, aws-cdk, amazon-dynamodb

I am attempting to implement something like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-aggregation.html) using AWS CDK, where I have a table that is written to every ~30 minutes, and an aggregator function that sums the values over each day. The original writes to the table will contain the following columns: `{player, timestamp, skills, activities}`. I want a sparse GSI to aggregate this daily, so these rows will have the columns `{player, date, skills, activities}`.

Here is my CDK code:

```py
class TrackerStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        """Construct a TrackerStack."""

        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        table = ddb.Table(
            self,
            "GranularTable",
            partition_key=ddb.Attribute(name="player", type=ddb.AttributeType.STRING),
            sort_key=ddb.Attribute(name="timestamp", type=ddb.AttributeType.STRING),
            encryption=ddb.TableEncryption.AWS_MANAGED,
            read_capacity=5,
            write_capacity=5,
            removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
            stream=ddb.StreamViewType.NEW_IMAGE,
        )
        table.add_global_secondary_index(
            index_name="DailyAggregate",
            partition_key=ddb.Attribute(name="player", type=ddb.AttributeType.STRING),
            sort_key=ddb.Attribute(name="date", type=ddb.AttributeType.STRING),
            read_capacity=3,
            write_capacity=3,
        )
        aggregation_lambda = _lambda.Function(
            self,
            "DailyAggregatorLambda",
            handler="aggregator.handler",
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset("lambda/aggregator"),
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            environment={"TABLE_NAME": table.table_name},
        )
        table.grant_read_write_data(aggregation_lambda)
        aggregation_lambda.add_event_source(
            lambda_event_sources.DynamoEventSource(
                hiscores_table,
                starting_position=_lambda.StartingPosition.TRIM_HORIZON,
                batch_size=1,
            )
        )
```

And here is my lambda code:

```py
ddb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = ddb.Table(os.environ["TABLE_NAME"])


def _timestamp_to_date(timestamp):
    return timestamp.split()[0]


def _image_map(_map):
    return _map["M"]


def _image_num(_map):
    return _map["N"]


def _image_str(_map):
    return _map["S"]


def handler(event, context):
    event_name = event["Records"][0]["eventName"]
    event_source = event["Records"][0]["eventSource"]
    logger.info(f"Processing Event '{event_name}' from source '{event_source}'.")

    new_image = event["Records"][0]["dynamodb"]["NewImage"]
    logger.info(f"Received image: {new_image}")

    if event_name == "INSERT":
        player_id = _image_str(new_image["player"])
        timestamp = _image_str(new_image["timestamp"])
        date = _timestamp_to_date(timestamp)

        # Increment divisor
        logger.debug(f"Incrementing divisor for {player_id}:{date}")
        table.update_item(
            Key={"player": player_id, "date": date},
            UpdateExpression="ADD divisor :incr",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={":incr": 1},
        )
```

When I write to the table, the aggregator is being correctly called, but it fails to write the new global secondary index with:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/aggregator.py", line 47, in handler
    table.update_item(
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

This makes sense, because the `date` attribute is not included in the rows written to the original table. However, it does not look like the `Table` API ([reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_dynamodb/Table.html)) provides an option to specify AttributeDefinitions. I tried writing an empty "date" column to the table when creating records so that it will be inferred in the schema, but got the following error (this error is for writing an empty string; got a similar error when writing a null value):

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values are not valid. A value specified for a secondary index key is not supported. The AttributeValue for a key attribute cannot contain an empty string value. IndexName: DailyAggregate, IndexKey: date
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/get_and_parse_hiscores.py", line 47, in handler
    table.put_item(Item=payload)
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

Is there a way to achieve this functionality using these tools?

**EDIT**: While the `Table` API does not allow users to specify a schema, the `CfnTable` API does ([reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_dynamodb/CfnTable.html)). I attempted to achieve this using `CfnTable`:

```py
class TrackerStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        """Construct a TrackerStack."""

        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        cfn_table = ddb.CfnTable(
            self,
            "GranularCfnTable",
            attribute_definitions=[
                ddb.CfnTable.AttributeDefinitionProperty(
                    attribute_name="date",
                    attribute_type="S",
                )
            ],
            key_schema=[
                ddb.CfnTable.KeySchemaProperty(
                    attribute_name="player", key_type="HASH"
                ),
                ddb.CfnTable.KeySchemaProperty(
                    attribute_name="timestamp", key_type="RANGE"
                ),
            ],
            global_secondary_indexes=[
                ddb.CfnTable.GlobalSecondaryIndexProperty(
                    index_name="DailyAggregate",
                    key_schema=[
                        ddb.CfnTable.KeySchemaProperty(
                            attribute_name="player", key_type="HASH"
                        ),
                        ddb.CfnTable.KeySchemaProperty(
                            attribute_name="date", key_type="RANGE"
                        ),
                    ],
                    projection=ddb.CfnTable.ProjectionProperty(projection_type="ALL"),
                    provisioned_throughput=ddb.CfnTable.ProvisionedThroughputProperty(
                        read_capacity_units=3,
                        write_capacity_units=3,
                    ),
                )
            ],
            provisioned_throughput=ddb.CfnTable.ProvisionedThroughputProperty(
                read_capacity_units=5,
                write_capacity_units=5,
            ),
            sse_specification=ddb.CfnTable.SSESpecificationProperty(sse_enabled=True),
            stream_specification=ddb.CfnTable.StreamSpecificationProperty(
                stream_view_type="NEW_IMAGE"
            ),
        )
        cfn_table.apply_removal_policy(RemovalPolicy.DESTROY)
        table = ddb.Table.from_table_arn(self, "GranularTable", cfn_table.attr_arn)
        aggregation_lambda = _lambda.Function(
            self,
            "DailyAggregatorLambda",
            handler="aggregator.handler",
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset("lambda/aggregator"),
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            environment={
                "TABLE_NAME": table.table_name,
            },
        )
        table.grant_read_write_data(aggregation_lambda)
        aggregation_lambda.add_event_source(
            lambda_event_sources.DynamoEventSource(
                table,
                starting_position=_lambda.StartingPosition.TRIM_HORIZON,
                batch_size=1,
            )
        )
```

However, `cdk synth` fails with the following error. I have had some trouble reconciling the level-1 CloudFormation APIs with the level-2 CDK APIs.

```
jsii.errors.JSIIError: DynamoDB Streams must be enabled on the table TrackerStack/GranularTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a good fist with your table design and using stream events to aggregate. Many struggle to get this far.
A couple problems need sorting to get things working. The good news is that the fix involves
removing complexity from your current setup.

[Edit] First things first: your update operation is bombing not because of a CDK or schema problem, but because `update_item` is missing the mandatory SK `timestamp` field.  Dynamo requires a unique value for the primary key - and you provided only a `player` value, not `timestamp`.  The index SK field `date` is not required.  That's the "sparse" in sparse index!

Next, the "schema". DynamoDB is almost schemaless - the almost being that it needs an explicit simple or compound primary key (PK or PK+SK). The L1 Construct `CfnTable.KeySchemaProperty` and `AttributeDefinition` sets these. But it's much, much easier to use the L2 `Table` `partition_key` and `sort_key` (and their index equivalents), which do the same thing.

Finally, a thought about table design. With the compound key pattern (used the OP link, too), you can implement your daily score pattern without a GSI.
You can get the latest day's score for player1 with the query `PK=player1 AND begins_with(SK, "Daily")` (with `Limit=1` and `ScanIndexForward=False`).

| `PK` | `SK` |
| --- | --- |
| `player1` | `PlayerInfo` |
| `player1` | `Daily#20211214` |
| `player1` | `Daily#20211215` |
| `player2` | `PlayerInfo` |
| `player2` | `Daily#20211214` |
| `player2` | `Daily#20211215` |

So in summary, back to your questions:

> How to write sparse Global Secondary Index rows AWS CDK 2.0?

You don't. You define the GSI and its keys in the CDK but use the SDK/Console/etc. to actually write the rows.<sup>*</sup>

> Is there a way to achieve this functionality using these tools?

Yes. Fix the query, Roll back the Table Construct to L2 and things will fall into place for you.

---

* You can use a CDK [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources-readme.html) to seed initial rows, but this is an advanced nice-to-have, not a must have.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick reply! A few questions:
1. I don't see any mention of an `IndexName` under `table.update_item`; am I misunderstanding? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_item

2. How do I set multiple sort keys using the L2 `Table` construct? Is it as simple as passing  a list? that contradicts what I see in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_dynamodb/Table.html

3. This is a great point, and I am going to try doing this instead now!

Comment: Glad to help!  Re: 1:  My bad, I fixed the answer.  Don't ask me how, but I misread `update_item` as `query`...  The storyline stays the same, though.

Comment: Re 2:  Conceptually, you don't "provide multiple sort keys" anywhere.  There is 0 or 1 Sort Key per table (and per index).  Perhaps this will help:  It is very common in Dynamo-land to name the key columns generically like `PK` and `SK`.   This key naming convention is essential for the column overloading in the [single table design pattern](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-a-single-table-design-with-amazon-dynamodb/) that all the cool kids use.

Comment: Re 2: If _still_ not convinced, open the DynamoDB console and try to create a table with multiple sort keys.

Comment: Ah okay. Where I was confused was on the fact that when inserting a row you wish to query with your GSI, you still have to include the PK and SK from the base table. So my rows with "date" would still need a "timestamp" in this schema. Thanks so much for the clarification. I agree that it's easier to just have a DAILY_SENTINEL to denote daily aggregation rows and reuse the timestamp sort key, and just implemented it this way. I'll post an answer shortly with my updated code, and accept your answer :). Thanks again for the help!!